# QGIS Redirecting WMS Request to localhost

Tags: qgis, wms

Whenever I add a WMS layer, from a server on the local intranet, the WMS request gets sent to localhost instead of the actual server I am referencing.

I am enclosing screenshots to make sure my problem is clear.

Here's how I add a new WMS connection:
[image]

When I hit connect, the layers from the server are actually listed as shown below, showing that atleast the GetCapabilities request is going through fine:
[image]

However, the map doesn't show up and I get a 'Connection Refused' label under the map layer:
[image]

When I look in the logs, I see that the error message references 'localhost' instead of the server I set:
[image]

Clearly, something seems off. If I just copy the request from the log window and replace the `localhost` with my server IP into Firefox, then the request goes through fine and I see the map in Firefox.

Stranger still, is that if I look at the layer information, the server URL is referenced correctly:
[image]

This seems to be happening only in Windows QGIS builds. On Linux, the map shows up as expected.

Here is the QGIS version information:
[image]

I am posting here to check if I am doing something wrong. I can't seem to find a QGIS bug that describes this issue so I want to rule out that I am getting something wrong.

Comment: Tick the check boxes "Ignore GetMap/GetTile URI" and "Ignore GetFeatureInfo URI". The WMS server must have wrong URL in GetCapabilities. You can check that from http://192.1681.31:19090/wms?map=world&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities. It is up to the WMS server how it can be configured right.

Comment: @user30184 You are absolutely right. It was indeed an error in my server configuration which sent the wrong URL as part of the GetCapabilities response. Once I fixed that, QGIS renders the map correctly. Can you please convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept it and mark this question as having been answered?

Comment: I think that question is not off-topic. It is rather common that at least UMN MapServers send  wrong URIs because they must be written by hand into map files. Some clients use always GetCapabilities URI also for GetMaps which can hide faulty settings. All WMS users should be aware of that.

Comment: I'm re-opening this to give @user30184 (or anyone else who may wish to as well) the opportunity to write up an answer.

Comment: @user30184 Yes, please convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: it's very bad practice for a client to assume that the GetCapabilities URL (end point) is the same as the GetMap or other request URLs.  There's no requirement in the WMS specification for this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here appears to be that the WMS GetCapabilities response has http://localhost... hard coded into it, whereas it should have http://192.168.1.38...

QGIS provides the option to ignore the reported GetMap and GetFeatureInfo service end points, (by ticking the check boxes), and instead use the URL you supplied to obtain the GetCapabilities response.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible to do in ArcMap also?

Comment: @EndreMoen I can't see any obvious way through standard interface to do the same in ArcMap (I'm on 10.3).  You might ask a new question on this and see if you get any ESRI experts giving you an alternate approach.  One possibility might be to set up a GDAL connector, but that's me thinking with a QGIS hat on.